# JTree nodes only show top half of panel

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a JTabbedPane with several tabs. Inside each tab I have a JScrollpane with a jtree inside. Each jtree node is another panel, containing other components, returned by a function. This works fine.

The problem is this:
On first show of the trees (all of them) the root nodes do not show completely. Only the top half shows. when double-clicked they show correctly if they have child nodes, if they don't nothing happens.

I can't find a way to show the nodes correctly the first time. I tried invalidate, validate paint, repaint, etc with several combinations.
Nothing works.

Comment: I'm assuming you're adding content after creating it? Try getting the TreePath to the first item and calling: tree.makeVisible(treePath); tree.scrollPathToVisible(treePath);  for that item.

Comment: Yes. it is added. it show but all the nodes eem to be the same heigth.
So it cuts the contents. only shows the top 50 to 60 points...

Comment: I've tried to invlidate, validate, paint, repaint all the components.
The tree it self, the Jpanel that is (becomes) the node, all the components inside the JPanel... Nothing seems to work.
I'm thinking it because the JTree is not drawn yet... system.out.println(this.getSize() returns Dimension[0, 0]
Wwhen i doubleclick a node that has children it expands and displays correctly, so, it fires the repaint event and i thought i could fire it on first display...
I dont know if it is possible...
Another way would be to call nodechanged...
But again, when?

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Added some screenshots...

Comment: what about calling pack() on the JPanel?

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

```
    ScrollPaneContainigTheTabel.setColumnHeader(new JViewport() 
    {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override public Dimension getPreferredSize() 
        {
          Dimension d = super.getPreferredSize();
          d.height = WHATEVER_HEIGHT_IS_NEEDED;
          return d;
        }
    });
```

Forcing the Table Header height solved the problem...
Now it recalculates the sizes correctly...

WHATEVER_HEIGHT_IS_NEEDED can be an int or a calculated value if you use (as i do) html to set more than one line in the header...